# Unable to add vnet subnet delegation in bicep. Code works but no errors

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-bicep

I have got the code base which can be found on https://github.com/jake7745/bicep-vnet with the initial work by github@ChristopherGLewis.

The code works well by creating a virtual network, and subnets the difficulty here is that one cannot add service delegation to the subnets.

```
param vNetName string    
param rgVnet string    
param subnetName string    
param subnetAddressPrefix string    
param delegations array = []

//Subnet with delegation

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-06-01' = {    
  name: '${vNetName}/${subnetName}'    
  properties: {     
    // delegations: delegations    
    delegations:[    
      {    
        name: 'delegation'    
        properties:{    
          serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms'    
        }    
      }    
    ]    
  }    
}
```

The code above is how a service delegation will be added, however I just cannot get it to work. The vnet and subnets are created, but without the delegation.

Any help or insight here would be appreciated.

To deploy the code, please check out the [repo](https://github.com/jake7745/bicep-vnet)
and run the code

```
$rgExists = az group exists --name 'rg-testing'

if ($rgExists -eq $true){
    Write-Output "Deleting the resource group"
    az group delete -y -n  rg-testing
}

az group create --name rg-testing --location CentralUS

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name network-deployment -resourcegroupName rg-testing -templatefile .\vNet.bicep -Templateparameterfile .\envs\stg.json
```

Update #1

What I did was to add a module which adds the delegation functionality, the end goal is for the delegation array to be passed onto the module for implementation, in the example I hardcoded the delegation and got he error below.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 17:54:35 - The deployment 'Deployvnet' failed with error(s). Showing 2 out of 2 error(s).
Status Message: Operation was canceled. (Code: Canceled)
 - Operation PutSubnetOperation (3434545f-6f7e-46c8-aaa2-5710c58acbac) was canceled and superseded by operation PutSubnetOperation (ca028961-7ada-45af-b8af-697006f000c6).
(Code:CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation)
Status Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details. (Code:
DeploymentFailed)
 - {
  "status": "Canceled",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Canceled'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Canceled",
        "message": "Operation was canceled.",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation",
            "message": "Operation PutSubnetOperation (3434545f-6f7e-46c8-aaa2-5710c58acbac) was canceled and superseded by operation PutSubnetOperation (ca028961-7ada-45af-b8af-697006f000c6)."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
} (Code:Conflict)
CorrelationId: ere34444-f496-4ec4-bbe1-d748542c3c1b
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name Deployvnet -resourcegroupName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

#Update 3

I have now fixed the code to get rid of the errors above, however what is happening is that when the subnets are delegated to a service, it removes the network security groups and the routing table, if the service delegation is disabled, then the network security groups and routing tables are created, what is happening is that the service delegation is causing the routing table and network security groups to get deleted.

One way around this is to use Az cli to add the service delegation. Is it possible to get this to work by reading the json configuration file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegation name differently.

This code works;

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param vNetName string = 'vnetGord'
param vNetAddressPrefix string = '10.0.0.0/16'
param subnetAddressPrefix string= '10.0.1.0/24'

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-11-01' = {
  name: vNetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [vNetAddressPrefix]
    }
  }
}

resource serverFarmSubnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-06-01' = {
  name: 'aSubnet'
  parent: vnet
  properties: { 
    addressPrefix: subnetAddressPrefix
    delegations: [
      {
        name: 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms'
        properties: {
          serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what I am finding is that if the NSG and routing tables are created, the delegation is deleted, if the delegation is created, the NSG and routing tables are deleted. I think the service delegation will need to be created outside of bicep as a workaround.

Comment: Are you creating multiple subnets at the same time? There are known issues when creating some networking resources concurrently. This means you'll need sequence the deployment order manually using DependsOn (I do this for NSG creation) or by creating at the parent level in the case of subnets & virtualNetworks.

Comment: Yes, multiple subnets at the same time. I have used the depends on functionality, and here is the issue, if the delegation runs first and the NSG and RT afterwards, the former gets created and deleted, so you end up with just the NSG and RT. If the delegation is created last, this is all you get, no NSG or RT.